# Can a View's setId() function create an id called R.id.whatever?

Tags: android, view

I have been creating all of my layouts in the XML files. However, I am now at a point where I should port a few of the pages into my java code to programatically build them.

I have found the View.setId() function, but it is giving me errors. I have read that you can just use positive integers to id your views, but I have a whole lot of views and would like to label them properly.

I know I could create a bunch of integers in my class with names, but is there a way to use `setId` to create a new `id` that can be referenced by calling `R.id.whatever`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. R is actually a class that gets generated. You can't add to it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can create some class IDS and store id constants there.

```
public class Ids  {
    private Ids(){}
    public static int BUTTON_OK = 0;
    public static int BUTTON_CANCEL = 1;
}
```

and refer to those id's.